# Is it possible to block an entire site to Google then list exceptions?

Tags: seo, google, web-crawlers

I usually disallow subdirectories in the robots.txt file and I was wondering if it's possible to do it the other way: block everything and list the main index file and the others pages I'd like search engines to index. Is that possible?

My current robots.txt is as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /example/
Disallow: /example/
Disallow: /example/
Disallow: /example/
Disallow: /example/
Disallow: /example/
Disallow: /example/
Disallow: yea.html
Allow: /
```

Comment: `Allow: /` is assumed so, in your example, you could achieve the same effect with only the `Disallow` directives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can disallow everything first, then allow the folders you want to be indexed.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /index.html
Allow: /example/
Allow: /example2/
Allow: /example3/
```

The reason this works is that Google (and Bing) follow CSS-style specificity rules when reading robots.txt files, where more specific rules take precedence over less specific ones. From Google's [robots.txt documentation](http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_txt.html):

> "...for allow and disallow directives, the most specific rule based on the length of the [path] entry will trump the less specific (shorter) rule. The order of precedence for rules with wildcards is undefined."

They give a table of examples on that page. Note that the *order* of the rules makes no difference to how they're interpreted; only the *length* of them matters. You could put the 'Disallow' rule in my example above at the end of the file and it would still work as intended.

Don't forget to [test your robots.txt file](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449) using [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/):

> To test a site's robots.txt file:
>
> 1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
> 2. Under Site configuration, click Crawler access
> 3. If it's not already selected, click the Test robots.txt tab.
> 4. Copy the content of your robots.txt file, and paste it into the first box.
> 5. In the URLs box, list the site to test against.
> 6. In the User-agents list, select the user-agents you want.