# What does "Allow: /" mean in a robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt

Please help me to understand the following code in *robots.txt*:

```
Allow: /
```

Answer (score 3):

Allow is not officially part of the [robots.txt specifications](http://www.robotstxt.org/) but the major search engines do honor it. But it is redundant as anything not explicitly blocked is allowed to be crawled.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use the `Allow` directive after a `Disallow` directive to allow crawlers to visit URLs that would otherwise be blocked by the `Disallow` directive.  See: [Is it possible to block an entire site to Google then list exceptions?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15331/is-it-possible-to-block-an-entire-site-to-google-then-list-exceptions)

As John says, the `Allow` directive is not standard, but it is supported by the major search engine spiders like Googlebot.